# Расположение блоков Css

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

Здраствуйте, есть задание по расположению блоков с точностью как на картинке с помощью FlexBox. Не понимаю как это сделать, пробовал создать три разных контейнера и расположить как align-self но не выходит. Заранее спасибо [image]

Comment: Создаём главный блок, делаем ему `position: relative`, создаём ещё два блока с абсолютным позиционированием, располагаем их по углам, каждому блоку создаём анимацию которая запускается при `:hover`'e. В главном блоке создаём ещё один блок с `display: flex` где будут располагаться наши два статических куба, дальше блоку с `flex` также выдаём абсолютное позиционирование и располагаем его в центре. Ничего сложного, повторно пройдите материал по пропорциям: `position`, `display`, `left / top / right / bottom`, `transform`, `background-image`, также по псевдоклассам (`:hover`, `:active` и т.п.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;  
  height: 250px;
  gap: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: max-content;
}

.wrapper div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(2), .wrapper div:nth-child(3) {
  align-self: center;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(4){
  align-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div> </div>
  <div> </div>
  <div> </div>
  <div> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, с анимацией постараюсь разобраться сам)))